# JavaScript: Reload/reparse part of document

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, reload, wmode

I am having a problem updating my page lay-out through JavaScript. I am editing an embed object (a YouTube video) to allow overlaying div's using `wmode="opaque"`. I am running in to a problem with Google Chrome, I edit the HTML using JavaScript, but the embed object stays in the foreground. Then we I edit the HTML (using the Developer Tools) with random changes like adding a return the embed element is reloaded and the behaviour is as expected.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue? I already tried using `window.location.reload(false);`, but that just refreshes the page with the version from the server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you actually remove the entire `<embed>` node from the DOM, give it `wmode=opaque`, and reinsert it?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc thanks, that works fine! Though it is not ideal, since the video buffers then is removed and then has to restart buffering again. 
Good solution, though I hope there will be a better one. ;-)